# Creating a table in opengauss is very slow, and the final prompt fails

Tags: sql, create-table, open-gauss

```
create table ADVISOR
(
    STU_ID varchar(5) not null,
    ID varchar(5),
    primary key (STU_ID)
);
```

> ERROR: Lock wait timeout: thread 140197302351616 on node dn_6001 waiting for ShareLock on transaction 7766 after 1200000.600 ms
> DETAIL: blocked by hold lock thread 140197328570112, statement <select * from advisor;>, hold lockmode ExclusiveLock.
> studentdb=>

Answer (score 0):

First look in the pg_stat_activity view, what is this session with pid "140197328570112" doing? If it can be forcibly closed, use the pg_terminate_backend function to turn it off.